# Mac not using correct Yarn version

Tags: npm, homebrew, yarnpkg

I installed Yarn I think from npm I believe a long time ago. But have since install the latest using brew. When I try to link to Yarn to brew's version it still points to the one manually installed.

How can I get terminal to use the brew version?

```
 ~  brew list --versions yarn
yarn 1.13.0
 ~  brew switch yarn 1.13.0
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0
2 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0
 ~  which yarn
/Users/lee/.yarn/bin/yarn
 ~  yarn --version
0.27.5
```

PATH

```
/Users/lee/.yarn/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/lee/Sites/AWS/ec2-api-tools-1.7.5.1/bin:/Users/lee/Sites/365TicketsGlobal/365tickets/data/scripts:/Users/lee/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Running Yarn command

```
 ~  yarn
yarn install v0.27.5
(node:48263) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.03s.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**homebrew** normally makes symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` for every executable binary it installs, so you need to have that on your `PATH` **before** the one your shell is currently finding in `/Users/lee/.yarn/bin`.

So you can either explicitly use this every time:

```
/usr/local/bin/yarn --version
```

Or set your `PATH` in your login profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

then log out and back in and then you can just use:

```
yarn --version
```

---

If you run this command:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin
```

you will see all the links you can use that **homebrew** has made pointing to the Cellar where the packages are actually installed.

Comment: I already have PATH in my profile.. And I can see yarn in bin: https://d.pr/i/RiDGU2

Comment: Ok, please run `echo $PATH` and also `type yarn` and paste the result into your original question by clicking `edit` under your question.

Comment: Please review above changes.

Comment: If you look at your PATH, you will see that the very first item is `/Users/lee/.yarn/bin` which is where your shell is finding `yarn`. It will find that because `/usr/local/bin` is **afterwards** in your PATH so it will never find or use **homebrew** `yarn`.

Comment: Me = dumbo,  ta very much